# Programmatically email .logarchive file

Tags: ios, swift

Looking at the changes introduced in 2016 to logging in iOS, I am wanting to locate the `.logarchive` file and attach it to an email programmatically in swift.

The following lead me to believe that this is not possible, but I was hoping someone out there has had some success.

- [Obtaining app logging](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2431/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017497-CH1-CONSOLELOG)
- [Release build debugging strategies](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2431/_index.html)
- [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/)

These articles seem to suggest that the user needs to explicitly connect their device to a computer to access the logs. I am wanting to have the user simply tap a button in the app and be able to send us their console logs.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 15 OSLog can be read programmatically using [OSLogStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog/oslogstore). Unfortunately there is no system provided function to write it to a logarchive. For now you need to build the body with formatting of the file yourself.